# How do I change my Windows XP password?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

How do I change my password in Windows XP?

Comment: -1 idiotic question but at least people are giving interesting answers.

Answer (score 6):

Control Panel > Users > [your username] > Change Password

Answer (score 5):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd>
2. Click *Change Password*

Comment: Only works if Welcome Screen is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

In case you were interested, you can also do this on the command line:

```
net user <your username> *
```

This will prompt you to enter a new password for your account. You can also substitute * for the actual password which will change it without any prompting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have owned another available admin password, it can work:

1. Log on your PC
2. Click *Start -> Control Panel -> Add or remove user account*
3. Select the account you want to reset
4. Click *Change or Remove the password*